# Mark test as passed from inside a fixture in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, python-unittest

With [`pytest.skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-skip) or [`pytest.xfail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-xfail), I can mark a test as skipped or xfailed from inside the fixture. There is no `pytest.pass`, though. How can I mark it as passed?

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixture():
    #pytest.skip()
    pytest.xfail()

def test(fixture):
    assert False
```

Comment: ending the test is a pass

Comment: return some value that means 'passed' to the test, I suppose. Not sure why you want to do this :)

Comment: raise an issue against ```pytest``` LOL

Comment: A test can only pass if it has executed and didn't raise. If a test didn't execute, it is skipped. If you have to lie and present the test as passed while it failed or didn't run, the test design is seriously wrong. While you can modify the test outcome from failed to passed, it's hidden for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i don't know the way to pass tests with fixtures, but you can use pytest.skip in your test with msg for example "pass" and the hook from conftest.py will check this "pass" msg and make test passed:

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(call):
    outcome = yield
    if outcome.get_result().outcome == 'skipped' and call.excinfo.value.msg == 'pass':
        outcome.get_result().outcome = 'passed'
```

**test_skip.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pytest


def test_skip_pass():
    pytest.skip('pass')


def test_skip_pass_2():
    pytest.skip('skip')
```

**result:**

> collecting ... collected 2 items
>
> test_skip.py::test_skip_pass PASSED [ 50%]
> test_skip.py::test_skip_pass_2 SKIPPED [100%]
> Skipped: skip
>
> ======================== 1 passed, 1 skipped in 0.04s =========================